Covert Markdown to LaTeX using Pandoc but exclude some text from appearing in .tex file
I have added several notes in my Markdown document but when converting the mardown to .tex file using Pandoc, I do not want those notes to appear in .tex file:
Here is the text with the notes:
"As the presence of a vinyl cutter is significantly associated with higher odds of collaboration with small companies, we can claim the results partially support the hypothesis." (note: please recheck the results)
Now is there any option for pandoc to exclude above note from appearing in .tex file when converting? Any symbole to add before the note to disappear or any other way? Thank you.

If you can use one of the standard way for comments in markdown, pandoc ignores them by default. E.g. [//]: # (Text of the comment), preceded and followed by an empty line. Or else an html comment.

IMHO this is more a question about how to mark comments in markdown or how to inject LaTeX code (like \begin{comment}…\end{comment} or \iffalse…\fi) into pandoc's markdown. Both is IMHO off-topic here.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to another site: perhaps superuser.stackexchange.com

I am not sure how universally work the already mentioned  syntax  [//]: # (Text of the comment) with all markdown engines, or  others that you can see in this question of  stackoverflow but beside it is a bit complex, for Rstudio users this syntax a have a big issuse: You only have to switch to the visual mode without export to anything to lost all the comments completely!  The visual mode mean reformat the source markdown to a concrete syntax (supposedly not a bug, but a feature), so that some code will be changed(e.g. inline footnotes) but at least this kind of comment is just deleted.
A convenient alternative for export markdown to LaTeX (or another formats) without any comment (but retain them in markdown), at least using pandoc, is use the HTML comments:
MWE.md
foo <!-- bar -->

Output to HTML:
$ pandoc -f markdown -t html foo.md

<p>foo <!-- bar --></p>

Note: If you need clear the comments also in the HTML source, simply add the option --strip-comments and use markdown_in_html_blocks extension when this cannot be applied inside raw HTML blocks.
Output to LaTeX:
$ pandoc -f markdown -t latex  foo.md

foo

That is, in LaTeX (and other commands) by default the comment is just ignored (i.e., deleted). Otherwise, remember --strip-comments
Note: For Quarto markdown you will prefer use  the syntax <!--# comment  --> as the # # prefix  trigger a special background highlight at least in the visual mode of Rstudio.
Another trick is a YAML comment:
foo 

---
# My comment
---

baz

The YAML comment will not produce any output in any other format, but having to add it separated from text with blank lines, mean that you can use only between paragraphs, whereas  HTML comments can be used anywhere.
